# Does the square root of $A$ conmute with $e^{At}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, radicals

I know that $A$ and $e^{At}$ conmute, as well as $A$ and $A^{1/2}$. So I am wondering if there is any chance that we can write:
$$A^{1/2} A A^{1/2}-A^{1/2} A e^{At} A^{1/2}= A^2(1-e^{At})$$

I have been trying to show this, but I'm stuck determining if $A^{1/2}e^{At}A^{1/2}=Ae^{At}$. If so, why or why not? and which characteristics do I need for $A$?

Comment: Well, are you assuming that $A$ is say hermitian positive semidefinite? This is the usual assumption one makes to talk about square root of matrices, to make sure that there is a "canonically" defined square root. In that case, one can write $A = UDU^*$, where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is hermitian positive semidefinite diagonal matrix. You then define $A^{1/2} = UD^{1/2}U^*$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to show this by using the definition of $e^{At}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} A^k$.

Since we have that $AA^{1/2}=A^{1/2}A$, then by induction one can show that $A^{k}A^{1/2}=A^{1/2}A^k$. Then you have:

$$A^{1/2}e^{At}=A^{1/2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} A^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} A^{1/2}A^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} A^k A^{1/2}=e^{At}A^{1/2}$$ as wanted.

Comment: Yes, but see my remark above. $A^{1/2}$ is in general not uniquely defined. For instance, all $3$ Pauli matrices square to the $2$ by $2$ identity matrix. So you usually make some assumptions on $A$ in order to talk about a uniquely defined square root of a matrix.

Comment: @Malkoun Sure, but regardless of which square root one chooses for $A^{1/2}$, it is still true that it commutes with $A$.

Comment: @ErickWong, a valid point, yes. I just wanted to comment about the non-uniqueness of square roots of matrices (generally speaking).